# barman check pg ,error in pg_receivexlog compatible: FAILED

Tags: postgresql-14, barman

Configuration

- PostgreSQL version: 14.2,
- pg_receivexlog version: None

I am having an issue with a barman - PostgreSQL configuration that manifests itself with the following error(s):

```
Server pg:
        WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)
        PostgreSQL: OK
        superuser or standard user with backup privileges: OK
        PostgreSQL streaming: OK
        wal_level: OK
        replication slot: FAILED (replication slot 'barman' doesn't exist. Please execute 'barman receive-wal --create-slot pg_harrison')
        directories: OK
        retention policy settings: OK
        backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
        backup minimum size: OK (0 B)
        wal maximum age: OK (no last_wal_maximum_age provided)
        wal size: OK (0 B)
        compression settings: OK
        failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
        minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 0 backups, expected at least 0)
        pg_basebackup: FAILED
        pg_basebackup compatible: FAILED (PostgreSQL version: 14.2, pg_basebackup version: Unknown)
        pg_basebackup supports tablespaces mapping: OK (pg_basebackup 9.4 or higher is required for tablespaces support)
        systemid coherence: OK (no system Id stored on disk)
        pg_receivexlog: FAILED
        pg_receivexlog compatible: FAILED (PostgreSQL version: 14.2, pg_receivexlog version: None)
        receive-wal running: FAILED (See the Barman log file for more details)
        archiver errors: OK
```

This is the barman configuration:

```
; PATH setting for this server
path_prefix = "/usr/pgsql-14/bin"
```

The barman log displays the following information:

```
2023-08-07 23:26:02,290 [5895] barman.server ERROR: ArchiverFailure:pg_receivewal not present in $PATH
2023-08-07 23:27:01,602 [5933] barman.server INFO: Starting receive-wal for server pg_harrison
2023-08-07 23:27:01,614 [5932] barman.wal_archiver INFO: No xlog segments found from streaming for pg.
2023-08-07 23:27:01,621 [5933] barman.server ERROR: ArchiverFailure:pg_receivewal not present in $PATH
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix the issue(s)?